# DIY Voltage and current regulator

Tags: batteries, current, analog, voltage-regulator, base

For DIY sake. I'm working on a current and voltage regulator and i found [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hFgP3nhWMmo)
Online. But instead of a c5200, I'm using the [d716](https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfdatasheet_utc/2sd718.pdf) for it. I have  a dynamo with 20 volt and 200ma current supply.Is it okay to try it out?

Comment: Please add a schematic image to your question so that you don't rely on a (potentially tenuous) link to something on YouTube that could be deleted by the originator and render your question invalid. Add other information in the video that may be needed. Have you tried simulating your circuit? What are your design aims?

Comment: Very few people are going to watch an 8 minute video when they could spend under a minute looking at a schematic diagram. From the data sheets the transistor you want to use has a somewhat lower power rating than the one in the video but will still be fine for a 20 volt 0.2 amp source.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here's the circuit in the video:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fViQ4s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit is not a "regulator" in any sense of the word. It is a simple emitter-follower that outputs some fraction of the input voltage. Both knobs adjust the voltage; there is no current sensing/regulation at all. In other words, it's a terrible circuit. Sure, the transistor substitution will work, but it'll still be a terrible circuit.

Comment: .. thanks by the way

Comment: It *is* a current regulator, just not a sharp one.  D1 compensates for the Vbe voltage and temperature coefficient.  That makes the transistor a comparator between the voltage across R4+R2 and the voltage across R5 + the external load.  The voltage across the load can increase until the voltage at the Q1 emitter equals the voltage at the top of R4.  Further increase in the effective impedance of the external load reduces the current through the Q1 base-emitter, and the Q1 collector current (and emitter current) decreases.

Comment: Alright. I'm gonna implement the circuit. But my choice for the transistor (i.e D716) is still valid right...?

Comment: @AnalogKid: That makes no sense at all. If we wanted to consider this a current regulator in any sense at all, it would have to limit the current in some way when the load impedance is *decreasing*. All you've described is how the circuit limits how high the output voltage can rise.